# Differentiability of Multivariable Functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Is there any way to proof that the function $\frac{2xy}{(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2}}$ is differentiable at each point of its definition domain?

I suppose that the function works as follows:

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{2xy}{(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2}} &  f(x,y)\neq (0,0)\\0 & f(x,y) = (0,0)\end{cases}$$

So the domain of the original function is $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,+\infty)$ and I suppose that I have to apply partial derivation at the point $(0,0)$ because there is where probably the function doens't have a derivate. Thanks

Comment: Do you know that continuity of the partials implies differentiability? Have you tried using the definition of differentiability to evaluate what happens at the origin?

Comment: mmm yeah, when I apply partial derivations to the function the partials are not continues when f(x,y)=0

Comment: Yes I use partial diferentials and then evaluate those derivatives at 0 but I get 0/0 :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, $f$ is clearly differntiable on $\Bbb R^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}$ as the quotient of two polynomial functions such that the denominator doesn't vanish.

Now, $f$ is not even continuous at $(0,0)$ (hence it's not differentiable at this point). Indeed
$$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x,x) = \lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{2x^2}{(2x^2)^2} = \lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{1}{2x^2} = +\infty.$$

Comment: why do you use f(x,x) ?

Comment: A function $f$ of 2 variables is continuous at a point $a$ if and only if the limit of $f$ at $a$ is $f(a)$ in **all the directions** around $a$. So I tried some possibilities ($x=0$, $y=0$, $x=y$) and the last one gave me the result.

Comment: wow thakns so much

Comment: You're welcome.